# How to use vue.js beforeMount lifecycle mehtod?

Tags: vue.js

i am trying to build a weather app in vue js for which i am getting lat and long when windows load and which is working fine. I have defined two variables as lat and long. I have set these variables to the real lat and long i am getting from javascript navigator object.
But when i try to pass these values to the real weather api its not working.
i have some code snippets down below

> App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>{{ lat }},{{ long }}</p>
    <pre> {{ forecast }} </pre>
    <Search></Search>
    <Main></Main>
    <ExtraData></ExtraData>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Search from "./components/Search.vue";
import Main from "./components/Main.vue";
import ExtraData from "./components/ExtraData";
import WeatherService from "./WeatherService";

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    Search,
    Main,
    ExtraData
  },
  data() {
    return {
      lat: "",
      long: "",
      forecast: "",
      test: "",
      city: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getLocation: function() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
          this.lat = pos.coords.latitude;
          this.long = pos.coords.longitude;
        });
      }
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.getLocation();
  },
  mounted() {
    WeatherService.getCurrentData(this.lat, this.long).then(data => {
      this.forecast = data;
    });
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}
</style>
```

> WeatherService.js

```
const apiKey2 = "f02444d5bb635b838a99faefef6eca70";
const api2 = `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${apiKey2}&query=`;

//getting current weather data from lat,long
const getCurrentData = async (lat, long) => {
  const response = await fetch(api2 + `${lat},${long}`);
  const currentLocationData = await response.json();

  return currentLocationData;
};

export default { getCurrentData };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getLocation` is likely an async function in which case you need to do something like this:

```
async created(){
  await this.getLocation();
  WeatherService.getCurrentData(this.lat, this.long).then(data => {
      this.forecast = data;
    });
```

you want yout 2 methods in the same lifecycle hook in order to be able to tell one to wait on the other. (In theory this could work in any lifecycle method)

Comment: try to console log what the first function is returning.